# Determine products of NH4NO3 hydrolysis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrolysis

What are the products of the following hydrolysis reaction? How do you know?

$$\ce{NH4NO3 + H2O <=> ?}$$

Comment: Please add what you have attempted towards solving the problem into the body of your question.  For more information, see the site's [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) for how to ask homework questions. Thanks!

Comment: We've spoken about this issue before.  Including what you already know in the body of the question helps both you and the person answering the question.

Comment: @jonsca This is not a homework question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will never happen. You can not hydrolyze a salt to any strong acid (nitric acid in your case) or base because the reverse reaction is predominant.

Answer (score -1):

The products will be $\ce{HNO3 + NH4OH}$.

This is because a salt hydrolysis reaction always produces an acid and a base. The $\ce{H+}$ in $\ce{H2O}$ will bond with $\ce{NO3-}$ to form $\ce{HNO3}$, a strong acid. The remaining $\ce{OH-}$ in $\ce{H2O}$ will bond with $\ce{NH4+}$ to form $\ce{NH4OH}$, a weak base.

Comment: Saying that is spontaneous for both ions violates thermodynamics.  Bad thing.